# Toggling programatically cellNav on and off in Angular UI-Grid

Tags: angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I'm looking for a way to turn on and off cell navigation of a grid while in edit mode. In my example http://plnkr.co/edit/GD1Blg8BTTmrLRR88UKe?p=preview`HERE` you can see I can enable and disable edit. Is it possible that I can do this for cell navigation as well? I need to use them both in concert. Just made an example with 2 switches in order to understand the logic. Afterwards, I'm thinking about performing those on and offs programatically.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure how to do it, but to help us, your Plunker needs fixing. You need to add ui-grid-cellnav into the "grid1" DIV in the HTML and add 'ui.grid.cellNav' as a module in the top line of app.js. Without these, the cellNav does not work either way.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes I'm aware of that. For now I just solved my problem by stopping using row selection. But I'm sure there must be a way to switch between add and edit modes. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Anyone managed to sort this?